# AFNetworking 2.0 success block main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I want to use `success` block in background. I use code:

```c
[manager POST:URLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *responseHeader, id responseBody) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {

    [self parseResponse:responseHeader and:responseBody forRequest:request];
    });
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"FAIL request: %@", error);
}];
```

In

```c
[self parseResponse:responseHeader and:responseBody forRequest:request];
```

I send `NSNotification` to update UI. But it not working...why?

Comment: Try to use a method in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications are sent synchronously and on the same thread when you post them so you need to switch back to the main thread, preferably before posting (though you could switch after receiving the callback).

You can use either `dispatch_async` or `performSelector:onMainThread:` to switch to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

UI Operations must be ran on the main thread.
When performed on a background thread - You will get a warning in the debugger about this and the update will happen a few seconds later (when the UI thread will actually get the call).
This is why you must use dispatch_async with the main thread to pop back to the main thread and perform all UI operations on that thread.

Do note - in AFNetworking - there are async load operations that happen on another thread anyhow and the completion blocks return on the same queue as they went out of - so in theory - if all you do is update UI - then you shouldn't handle it in your code too.